# How can i change directory in shell script with variables

Tags: shell, active-directory, directory

this script file name "1sr" and i can work in terminal ". 1sr"

i want to change directory "home/byram/workspace/1/src/com/seri/*"

```
#!bin/sh
f=$(basename $0 | tr -d "sr")
pth="/home/byram/workspace/$f"
my1=$(ls $pth/src/com/seri)
cd $etc/src/com/seri/$my1
```

after ". 1sr" command f variable set "bash"
how can i fix it?

Comment: Since your script isn't parameterized in anyway, why not just hardcode the path? `cd /home/byram/workspace/1/src/com/seri`

Comment: bacause i have many project have "1","2","3","4" directories @chepner

Comment: But the project  is embedded in the name of the script itself. Do you have identical copies with different names to handle the different projects?

Comment: yes i have many projects in my workspace under like 1,2,3,4,5,etc folders @chepner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a function called "prj" to put in your `.bashrc`:

```
prj () {
    cd /home/byram/workspace/"$1"/src/com/seri
}
```

Then use it like this

```
prj 1    # Switch to ...1/src/com/seri
prj 2    # Switch to ...2/src/com/seri
```

Comment: but i also want to reach in ../src/com/seri/* files eg. ../seri/one/

Comment: You can only have one working directory at a time. If there is only one subdirectory in `seri`, then just add an asterisk to the end of the command to match whatever that directory is. If there is more than one subdirectory, I don't know what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

i add in `.bashrc` this lines:

```
wr (){
cd /home/byram/workspace/"$1"/w
v1=$(ls /home/byram/workspace/"$1"/src/*/*)
v2=$(ls /home/byram/workspace/"$1"/src/*)
v3=$(ls /home/byram/workspace/"$1"/src/)
echo "$v3.$v2.$v1"    
}
```

works for any project eg. com.example.abc,org.samp.xyz

thanks for @chepner